# Cannot save all decimal places

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

I have the following column definition in mariadb:

`multiplier double`

In my entity class, I have the following column:

`@Column(name="multiplier", precision=15)
private Double itemMultiplier;`

I already specified the precision but still the data saved in the table is limited up to 5 decimal digits only.  I logged the value of `itemMultiplier` and it's 0.458327459574.  But in the table, the value saved is just 0.45833.

I also tried using `double(22,15)` and `decimal(22,15)` in the column `multiplier`, it also didn't work.

How can I save all the decimal places?  I also tried using `BigDecimal` for `itemMultiplier`, it didn't work.

Comment: It seems like the issue is with your database, not the entity. Is it possible that the database is restricting the precision to 5? Like in SQL, if you declare it as `Number(30,15)`, you're saying the field has **30 digits** with **15 of those can be decimal digits**. See [MariaDB - Double](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/double/) for details.

Comment: how to know if the database is restricting the precision to 5? i also tried double(22,15) and decimal(22,15), it didn't work

Comment: How was your query constructed?

Comment: I'm just viewing from sql client.  i created the table using `CREATE TABLE tablename {... multiplier double(22,15), ...);`  exporting it to csv also gives me only 5 decimals

Comment: I meant how are you saving the value to the table? How are you doing it in Java?

Comment: i have a dao that extends `JpaRepository`, then i create the entity using `new`, set the multiplier, then call `dao.saveAll()`

Comment: i think everything's ok now.  it seems that using a client and exporting from client, i only get 5 decimals... but when i query from java, it gives me the all decimals

Comment: You were exporting from the client? What were you using to read the values? Excel? Microsoft Excel tends to truncate it, but you can tell it to add more decimal points and they will bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

`double(22,15)` is an abomination.  You get unnecessary rounding at the bottom and truncation at the top.  If you are going to use `DOUBLE`, use just plain `DOUBLE, which gives you about 16 *significant* digits.

"Only 5 decimal places in the output"?  Perhaps the formatting rounded to 5 decimal places, not the data.

You say

> I already specified the precision...

By what means did you specify the precision?

Please provide the SQL statements involved.  In particular `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to figure out whether Java is messing things up or MariaDB is.

Another thing to try is to display not just `multiplier`, but `100*multiplier` -- report back whether you get `45.83275` or `45.83300`.

Comment: i multiplied by 100 and it is saved as 45.83275.  i specified the precision meaning in the entity column definition i put `@Column(name="multiplier", precision=15)`.  in the `create table` i just specify the column as `multiplier double`

Comment: i think everything's ok now.  it seems that using a client and exporting from client, i only get 5 decimals... but when i query from java, it gives me the all decimals

Comment: The client is the villain!